# How to filter query using Regular Expression?

Tags: sql, regex, alibaba-cloud, regexp-like

I build regular expression script and already tested on https://regexr.com/ to make sure that I capture the correct data I want to get.

I am using alibaba platform, daas to be exact and perform a query on our table.

```
> select count(1) from ip_tbl
> where ip_address is not null
```

Result: **51,000 records**

Now I want to use my regular expression on IP address that I have been tested, this has to ensure that I capture all the IP on the said table.

```
> select count(1) from ip_tbl
> where ip_address regexp '\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'
```

Result: **0 records**

I tried different function such as RLIKE and REGEXP but it won't work. Please somebody help me regarding this matter. TIA

Comment: What's the underlying SQL platform?

Comment: @Nick I guess it's MySQL.

Comment: @JLDelosReyes Give more detail about the list of IP Address capturing and ignore-capturing

Comment: If it's MySQL, at the very least you will need to escape the ```\``` i.e. `'\\b(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}'`

Comment: I want to capture ipv4 or ipv6. Sample 123.456.789.000 or kind.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.